# How to enqueue sequential work without WorkContinuation

Tags: android, android-workmanager, kotlin-coroutines

Using WorkManager 2.1.0,

How can I enqueue a set of operations without using WorkContinuation? If I have

```
val firstSet = firstWorkers()
val secondSet = secondWorkers()
```

How can I execute the `secondSet` after the `firstSet` has completed?

I **do not** want to chain the work as I still want the `secondSet` to execute even if a call fails within the `firstSet`

---

Things I've tried,

*enqueue*

```
workManager.enqueue(firstSet)
workManager.enqueue(secondSet)
```

I would assume the `enqueue` function would cause the operations to run in order, however they run out of order I'm assuming this is due to multi-threads?

*LiveData*

`workManager.enqueue().state().observe {}` and running `workManager.enqueue(secondSet)` after a `SUCCESS`

*Async/Await*

`coroutineScope.async { workManager.enqueue().await() }`

even though the result is returned sequentially, the network calls still happen out of order, in some cases `firstSet` doesn't execute until the end.

---

The only *"solution"* I could find was to return a `Result.success()` from the `doWork()` function even if it fails, that seems wrong.

How can I execute operations sequentially even if one of the previous calls fails?

Answer (score 5):

As you wrote, when you build a `WorkCountination`, if one of the worker fails, all the chain is marked as failed and the following worker are not executed.

This is also true when you use unique work requests with the [`APPEND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingWorkPolicy.html#APPEND) `ExistingWorkPolicy`; in this case you're also building a chain of work so, if one of the worker fails, all the following worker aren't executed.

I you want to have a guaranteed order, and you don't mind if a previous worker fails I can only think of two solutions:

1. Always return `Result.Success(dataOut)` from your worker. You define what is success, for WorkManager a failure in a chain means that everything in the chain needs to fails. This is not what you want so you may add some additional information in the `dataOut` object.
2. You enqueue the second worker from inside the first one, independently of its result.

Personally I prefer the first option, you just need to agree on what is success and failure with WorkManager and use the Data object that you return in the `Result.Success()` call if you need to handle the "unsuccessful" case.

Comment: I figured the first option was the only real way of accomplishing this, thanks for the confirmation. Do you know if there's any plan to allow a chain to continue even if a previous worker fails, or at least queue the operations in sequence without a continuation?

Comment: It's a request that the team has already seen and that is tracking. If you have additional use cases, or you just want to add your support for this change you can use this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/134613984